# How to use Simple_navigation_goals?

Tags: rviz, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to figure out how to read navigation position of turtlebot in rviz (saved map,or new), and translate that info to write it in the Simple_navigation_goals.cpp. Does the cpp file send a goal similar to the way rviz does in gmapping, or does it just tell it to move forward then move left ..etc . How can I get the turtlebot to draw out a square. And how can I get turtlebot to go to a fixed location ? Thanks --Atom--

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11998/how-to-use-simple_navigation_goals-?/) by [Atom](https://answers.ros.org/users/636/atom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 458 on 2011-11-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2013-11-10**:
@Atom, I am little bit confused with TurtleBot since there are two sources to download package; one is from here https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_apps and other one is https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_simulator. Which one you have used? Which version of ROS and Gazebo are you using?

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2013-11-10**:
@ Atom which tutorials you are referring; this one http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/TurtleBot or the other one from here  http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_simulator. Can we modify the autonomous behavior in anyone of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you referring to [this tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/SendingSimpleGoals) ?

It does send a goal similar to rviz does (to move_base, not gmapping). It does not tell the robot to go forward, left, etc., it just tells it where the robot should end up and lets the move_base node figure out how to do that best.

Going to a fixed location is the intended purpose, just set the fixed location as target pose and give it a the proper frame_id (e.g. map).

As for the example from the tutorial that moves the base 1m forward. It only does that by telling the robot the goal is 1m ahead relative to the robot (i.e. /base_link). Setting the target 1m ahead will usually result in the robot, just driving ahead for 1m, but it doesn't need to do that exactly.

To drive a square, there thus are two possibilities:

1. Choose the 4 cornerpoints of a square as targets in the map and give those as goals.
2. Use the "go X meters ahead trick" 4 times, you should also be able to turn 90° in the same way.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Atom](https://answers.ros.org/users/636/atom/) on 2011-11-21**:
Thanks for clearing that up for me.. makes sense.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-11-21**:
The goal is given with respect to the frame_id given. If it is an fixed frame_id (e.g. /map) it is an x/y goal in the map, if it is relative (e.g. /base_link) it is an x/y goal relative to the robot's current perspective.

**Comment by [Atom](https://answers.ros.org/users/636/atom/) on 2011-11-20**:
Thanks for the reply.. I also was wondering if the goal is set in perspective to the current position, wouldn't that make it hard to write x/y goals intended for a saved map in Rviz (like a kitchen) seeing as turtlebot might start off from various positions with in a map?

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-11-04**:
@dornhege iis it possible to change the goal your giving? for example i give it the (3,5) and before it arrives send a new goal to (2,4) is it possible? And is it possible to get the position of the robot at a certain time?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm doing something like this to add a user interface.  You might want to [see the code here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Efuzzgun/buttonui-ros-pkg/trunk/view/head:/src/buttonui.cpp) for an example of setting initial pose and goal positions.

---

Originally posted by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) with karma: 995 on 2011-11-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Atom](https://answers.ros.org/users/636/atom/) on 2011-11-20**:
Thanks so much for the great write up... Looking forward to installing this on my turtlebot :) many thanks. --Atom--

**Comment by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on 2011-11-20**:
For more information see http://sluggish.homelinux.net/wiki/Buttonui-ros-pkg

**Comment by [Atom](https://answers.ros.org/users/636/atom/) on 2011-11-20**:
-LCD to display current position of turtlebot. With that and your code I think turtlebot would be soo much more Amazing...

**Comment by [Atom](https://answers.ros.org/users/636/atom/) on 2011-11-20**:
I noticed your comments in the code but a brief description might help me get a clearer picture of whats happening. BTW I think what you are working on looks Awesome... Seems you are adding buttons for arduino to set goals or positions .?.. I was thinking of doing something like that with a Serial -

**Comment by [Atom](https://answers.ros.org/users/636/atom/) on 2011-11-20**:
Thanks for the link... I'm glad to see someone else is interested in this topic.. Wow your file is quite complex. I'm not much of a programmer. Might take me some time to figure this out, but it looks promising. Could you give a brief description of what the code is doing so that I can sort it out?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all, we did [this](http://wiki.ros.org/yocs_waypoints_navi) package recently for a demo: allows you to set waypoints throw where the robot will go before reaching the final goal. It's a quite simplistic and fast implementation for a demo, but anyway it can be useful for you. It's still not released, so you need to download and compile the code. Tell me if you have any problem using it.

*Update*

You normally get the pose of the robot [with a tf listener](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20%28C%2B%2B%29).

If you send a new goal, the previous one is preempted (cancelled).
You can send goals relative to any reference frame. Then move base will convert it to map reference system. All this is quite well explained on [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/SendingSimpleGoals).

---

Originally posted by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) with karma: 2284 on 2013-11-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-11-05**:
@jorge im using the simple_navigation_goal and i cant find a lot of information, how do you cancel one goal and post a new one before the first goal is reached? really appreciate your help

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-11-05**:
What you mean with "use"? You send goals to simple_navigation_goal topic? To cancel current goal you send a actionlib_msgs/GoalID message to /move_base/cancel topic. That's the simple way; the other option is to write your client for move_base action server, so you get more control of the navigation

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-11-05**:
Here is an example script:
https://github.com/yujinrobot/korus/blob/hydro-devel/korus_scripts/scripts/cancel_move_base_goal

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-11-07**:
@jorge @Atom how can i obtain the position of the robot at a given time? In simple_navigation_goals you post goals related to the actual position of the robot but can i get the actual position of the robot when the goal is posted? thanks